# Open subset of the space of matrices

Tags: general-topology, matrices

This question comes from the process of my learning about Grassmann manifolds.

Suppose that $M(m,n)$ is the set of real $n \times m$ matrices, where $n>m$. Let $F(m,n)$ be a subset of $M(m,n)$ such that each matrix element in $F(m,n)$ has rank $m$. We regard $M(m,n)$ as $\mathbb{R}^{m \cdot n}$, hence, the topology on $M(m,n)$ is identify with the common topology on $\mathbb{R}^{m \cdot n}$.

**My question:**

Why $F(m,n)$ is an open subset of $M(m,n)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\in F(m,n)$. Since $A$ has rank $m$, it has some $\;m\times m$ nonvanishing minor. As the determinant function is continuous, the same minor remains nonzero under small perturbations. Obviously, no element in $F(m,n)$ has rank greater than $m$, and we are done.

Comment: But the domain of determinant function is not $F(m,n)$.

Comment: $A$ has $m$ independent rows, without loss of generality, these are rows $1,\ldots,m$. We consider only the determinant of the matrix that consists of these rows.

Comment: Can we take $C^m_n$ determinant functions $f_i$ such that the domain of $f_1$ is the first $m$ rows in the matrix, ... , and the domain of $f_{C^m_n}$ is the last $m$ rows ?  That is, specifically, for each fixed $i$, $f^{-1}_i (\mathbb{R}/\{ 0 \})$ is an open set in $M(m,n)$. Since $F(m,n)$ is the union of these sets $f^{-1}_i (\mathbb{R}/\{ 0 \})$ for $1 \leq i \leq C^m_n$, we can get this result. Is my reasoning right ?

Comment: Yes, totally. Right.